# referencing stdout in a command that has been piped into

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I want to make a simple dmenu command that reads a file of commands and names. Then takes the names and displays them using dmenu then takes dmenu's output and runs the associated command using the file again.

I got to the point where dmenu displays the names, but I don't really know where to go from there. Learning bash is a really daunting task to me and I don't really know where to start with this seemingly simple script/command.

here is the file:

```
Pushbullet
google-chrome-stable --app=https://www.pushbullet.com
Steam
steam
Chrome
google-chrome-stable
Libre Office
libreoffice
Transmission
transmission-qt
Audio Control Panel
sudo pavucontrol & bluberry
```

and here is what I have so far for my command:

```
awk 'NR % 2 != 0' /home/rocco/programlist | dmenu | ??(grep -l "stdout" /home/rocco/programlist....)
```

It was my thinking that I could somehow pipe into grep or awk with the name of the application then get the line number then add one and pipe that into sh.

Thanks

Comment: If you're running Bash 4, you can use [Associative Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Associative_Arrays) to store the name of the command as the key and the command itself as the value. Though I suggest you to read [Bash FAQ 50 (I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and decide what is the best approach for your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with `dmenu` but if I understand how it works correctly, this should do what you want. Wrapping a command in `$(…)` returns the output as a variable, which we can pass on to another command.

```
#!/bin/bash
plist="/home/rocco/programlist"
# pipe every second line to dmenu
selected=$(awk 'NR % 2 != 0' "$plist" | dmenu)
# search for the selected item, get the command after it
cmd=$(grep -A1 "$selected" "$plist" | tail -n 1)
# run the command
$cmd
```

Worth mentioning a mistake in your question. `dmenu` sends to `stdout`, or standard output, but the next program in line would be reading `stdin`, or standard input. In any case, `grep` can't take patterns on standard input, which is why I've saved to a variable instead of trying to pipe it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `programlist.txt` in the working directory you can use:

`awk 'NR%2 !=0' programlist.txt |dmenu |awk '{system("grep --no-group-separator -A 1 '"'"'"$0"'"'"' programlist.txt");}' |awk '{if(NR==2){system($0);}}'`

Note the quoting of the `$0` in the first awk envocation.  This is necessary to get names with spaces in them like "Libre Office"